# Matlab subplot shows tiny images

Tags: image, matlab, matlab-figure, subplot

I have an algorithm that does a set of 8 image processing operations in an input image and then I want to show the output of each of them in a grid of 8 images. The problem is that I want to show image by image after each of the operations ends. By using subplot and imshow the image outputs I want to show in the grid are small.

Here is some piece of my code

```
output1=image_operation(input_image);
subplot(4,4,1);
imshow(output1);
```

I have heard about imdisp and montage functions, but they don't do what I want. I want to show the first image when the first algorithm ends, then the second image together with the first when the second algorithm ends and so on. What these functions do is showing all images at once and I don't want this.

Is there anything I missed?

Comment: Try this: `drawnow` after you plot  something ! Also consider adding some code in your post so that we may identify the problem in a better way

Comment: @Sardar_Usma please see my edition in the question. drawnow function didn't work. Thank you.

Comment: I don't think this code helps in any way. Did you try `drawnow`? Also  try to add a  [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: The code is exactly this way. Of course only image_operation() function changes. Function drawnow doesn't change how the images are displayed. I tried to insert it after subplot() and then after imshow() and Nothing changes :-(.

Comment: Suppose you want to display the same image 8 times using subplot function. How to make images bigger? if it is possible to do this then my problem is solved.

Comment: if there are 8 images, why are you using `subplot(4,4,x)` and not `subplot(4,2,x)` or `subplot(2,4,x)`. Try using any of these instead

Comment: what a rookie error. I think you got the point. I am satisfied with image sizes now. Can you answer the question and then I will mark your answer as the one that solved my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why your output images are too small is that you want to plot 8 images but you're using subplot command for 16 images i.e. `subplot(4,4,x)`. Since you want to plot 8 images using subplot, use any of following instead:

`subplot(4,2,x)`
or `subplot(2,4,x)`